# C# Lists reference with two?

Tags: c#, list, reference

I need 2 lists which are separate and one list containing the items of these two lists.

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();

List<int> list3 = list1 & list2
```

When I add some integers in list1, I would like them to appear in list3 as well.
I want the same behavior when a new item is added into list2.

A reference of more than one lists.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't do that with `List<T>` directly. However, you could declare:

```
IEnumerable<int> union = list1.Union(list2);
```

Now that will be lazily evaluated - every time you iterate over `union`, it will return every integer which is in either `list1` or `list2` (or both). It will only return any integer once.

If you want the equivalent but with concatenation, you can use

```
IEnumerable<int> concatenation = list1.Concat(list2);
```

Again, that will be lazily evaluated.

As noted in comments, this doesn't expose all the operations that `List<T>` does, but if you only need to read from the "combined integers" (and do so iteratively rather than in some random access fashion) then it may be all you need.

Comment: `List<T>.AddRange()`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That wouldn't provide the semantics requested.

Comment: I can't decipher from the question whether the OP wants duplicates or not, in order or not.

Comment: Jon, that assumes that he only ever needs operations `IEnumerable<T>` exposes, rather than, say, what would be exposed through an `IList<T>`

Comment: thanks for the quick and helpful answers to everyone! And sorry for my bad english, if anyone had Problems to understand me.

Comment: @Servy: Indeed - but I'd argue that if other operations are required, far more information about expected behaviour is also required before we can answer. I've added a bit at the end of the answer to indicate this.

Comment: @JonSkeet Most of them would fall into place fairly easily; but there would be some operations with ambiguous semantics, yes.  Exposing read only list semantics however would be quite easy, and I wouldn't expect it to have any real ambiguities.

Comment: @Servy: If it needs to be lazy though, just using `ElementAt()`, `Count()` etc is likely to be just as good...

Comment: @JonSkeet It would be fairly straightforward to have a class that holds onto two lists, and in the indexer it determines if the index fits in the first list, if so, calls it, if not, indexes the appropriate item in the second list (adjusting the index appropriately), etc.  You could do the same thing for most all operations, read only or not.  The ambiguities arise when you, for example, want to insert an item on the boundary between lists.  Should it go in the end of the first, or the start of the second?  A read only version wouldn't have those problems.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, that's true... I hadn't considered that. I guess we'll have to see what the OP actually needs...

Comment: I made an implementation mostly to see if there would be any interesting problems.  It's in my answer.  The inserting on the border of lists is probably the roughest issue.  What to do when `Add` is called and there *are no lists* in the collection of lists is also an interesting question about what should happen.  Most of the rest pretty much wrote itself.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible?

Not with `List` since it's a static data structure - however you could use a *query* that is the concatenation of the two lists.  Then whenever you enumerate the query it will show the current contents:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
List<int> list2 = new List<int>();

IEnumerable<int> list3 = list1.Concat(list2);
```

But as soon as you materialize the query into a data structure (by calling `ToList`, `ToArray`, etc.) the contents are static and will not update if one of the underlying lists updates.

Answer (score 2):

No.  You can create your own custom type that exposes methods similar to what a `List<T>` does (an indexer, `Add`, `Remove` methods, etc.), possibly even implementing `IList<T>`, but it wouldn't be a `List<T>`.

```
public class CompositeList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private IList<IList<T>> lists;
    public CompositeList(IList<IList<T>> lists)
    {
        this.lists = lists;
    }
    public CompositeList(params IList<T>[] lists)
    {
        this.lists = lists;
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        int globalIndex = 0;
        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            var localIndex = list.IndexOf(item);
            if (localIndex >= 0)
                return globalIndex + localIndex;
            else
                globalIndex += list.Count;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        //note that there is an ambiguity over where items should be inserted
        //when they are on the border of a set of lists.
        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            //use greater than or equal instead of just greater than to have the inserted item 
            //go in the later of the two lists in ambiguous situations, 
            //rather than the former.
            if (index > list.Count)
                index -= list.Count;
            else
            {
                list.Insert(index, item);
                return;
            }
        }
        //TODO deal with having no lists in `lists`
        //TODO deal with having only empty lists in `lists`
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            if (index > lists.Count)
                index -= list.Count;
            else
                list.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var list in lists)
            {
                if (index > lists.Count)
                    index -= list.Count;
                else
                    return list[index];
            }

            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }
        set
        {
            foreach (var list in lists)
            {
                if (index > lists.Count)
                    index -= list.Count;
                else
                    list[index] = value;
            }

            throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        if (!lists.Any())
            lists.Add(new List<T>());

        lists[lists.Count - 1].Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        foreach (var list in lists)
            list.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return lists.Any(list => list.Contains(item));
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        if (array.Length - arrayIndex - Count < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("The array is not large enough.");
        int iterations = Math.Min(array.Length, Count);
        for (int i = arrayIndex; i < iterations; i++)
            array[i] = this[i];
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return lists.Sum(list => list.Count); }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        foreach (var list in lists)
        {
            if (list.Remove(item))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return lists.SelectMany(x => x).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```